# No operating system selection screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have been using Windows 10 as my default OS. A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 through USB. When I start my PC I can't see any OS selection screen. It boots Windows 10 directly. But if I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> repeatedly right after switching the PC on it takes me to the menu shown below. In that screen I choose <kbd>F9</kbd>. Then it shows another screen (boot manager screen).

What should I do display the OS selection screen right after turning the PC on?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I had the **EXACT SAME** problem and I solved it like this:

- From that page (in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jklt.jpg)) press <kbd>F10</kbd> to go to **BIOS Setup**
- Navigate to **System Configuration**
- It should look like this:
  [image]
- Now select **Boot Options**
- Looks like this now:
  [image]
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on **OS boot Manager**
- Now using <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> make **ubuntu (THOSHIBA ****)** as the first option
- Like this: 
  [image]
- Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and save the settings by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Now you should see the **GRUB**

**NOTE:** If **ubuntu option** is not available in the **OS boot manager** you should disable **SECURE BOOT** (and Legacy support too) and save and Restart.

Now try the above steps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu ! As you are a new member on this platform ... If this answer solved your problem, please do not forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this answer, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Boot your computer in **Legacy Mode.**
Save changes and Restart the computer.
Press `Esc` Key -> `F9` Button to Boot Device option.
You will get Boot Device option Screen,from that you have some list of entry named starting from

> OS Boot Manager
>   Ubuntu(HP15EBA..).

Click that Ubuntu(HP15EBA...),now you will get default GRUB Boot Menu.
Select Ubuntu to boot into Ubuntu OS.

Note: Suggested for **HP Computers** have **Insyde BIOS**.

Answer (score 0):

If using a virtual-box just press the Escape key as soon as it boots to see the OS-choices. For BIOS setup Press F12 while booting.